# sendAndConfirm transaction signers

Tags: web3.js, send-transaction, ata

I'm taking my initial steps in Solana / Anchor / Smart Contracts / etc etc.
My doubt is regarding the creation of the ATA. After creating all the needed steps, when trying to send and confirm the transaction, it only works (code provided below) when I add the mint keypair and the account keypair as signers. Shouldn't it work only with the mint keypair as signer?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using `baseaccount` to pay state rent inside `createInitializeMintInstruction`.